# Concise way of creating a IntRange out of an Int

Tags: lambda, kotlin

I want to create a collection (in this case a map due to the extended function 'groupBy') that maps an IntRange to a list of a data class, which members are determined whether an int inside the data class is within the IntRange.
The IntRanges are 0..9, 10..19, 20..29, etc.

Concrete example:

```
data class Trip(
    val (...)
    val distance: Double
) 

[...]

val mappedTrips = trips.groupBy {
    ((it.duration-(it.duration)%10))..((it.duration-(it.duration)%10)+9) }
```

Explicitly the

```
((it.duration-(it.duration)%10))..((it.duration-(it.duration)%10)+9)
```

part seems to be not very concise, hard to read and therefore I was wondering if there is a way to make it more efficient, meaning more easy to read, concise.

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

```
TaxiPark Class


package taxipark

data class TaxiPark(
        val allDrivers: Set<Driver>,
        val allPassengers: Set<Passenger>,
        val trips: List<Trip>)

data class Driver(val name: String)
data class Passenger(val name: String)

data class Trip(
        val driver: Driver,
        val passengers: Set<Passenger>,
        // the trip duration in minutes
        val duration: Int,
        // the trip distance in km
        val distance: Double,
        // the percentage of discount (in 0.0..1.0 if not null)
        val discount: Double? = null
) {
    // the total cost of the trip
    val cost: Double
        get() = (1 - (discount ?: 0.0)) * (duration + distance)
}
```

Task

Find the most frequent trip duration among minute periods 0..9, 10..19, 20..29, and so on.
Return any period if many are the most frequent, return `null` if there're no trips.

Test sample

```
class TestTask5TheMostFrequentTripDurationPeriod {

    private fun testDurationPeriod(expected: Set<IntRange?>, tp: TaxiPark) {
        val actual = tp.findTheMostFrequentTripDurationPeriod()
        val message = "Wrong result for 'findTheMostFrequentTripDurationPeriod()': $actual."
        if (expected.size <= 1) {
            Assert.assertEquals(
                    message + tp.display(),
                    expected.firstOrNull(), actual)
        } else {
            Assert.assertTrue(message +
                    tp.display() +
                    "\nPossible results: $expected" +
                    "\nActual: $actual\n",
                    actual?.let { it in expected } ?: expected.isEmpty())
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun test00() = testDurationPeriod(setOf(null), taxiPark(0..1, 0..10))

    @Test
    fun test01() {
        // The period 30..39 is the most frequent since there are two trips (duration 30 and 35)
        testDurationPeriod(setOf(30..39), taxiPark(1..3, 1..5,
                trip(1, 1, duration = 10),
                trip(3, 4, duration = 30),
                trip(1, 2, duration = 20),
                trip(2, 3, duration = 35)))
    }

    @Test
    fun test02() = testDurationPeriod(setOf(30..39), taxiPark(0..5, 0..9,
            trip(0, listOf(2, 9), duration = 14, distance = 25.0),
            trip(1, listOf(8), duration = 39, distance = 37.0, discount = 0.2),
            trip(5, listOf(0, 5), duration = 27, distance = 28.0, discount = 0.3),
            trip(4, listOf(0, 6), duration = 33, distance = 14.0),
            trip(2, listOf(5, 1, 4, 3), duration = 2, distance = 15.0),
            trip(4, listOf(7), duration = 27, distance = 2.0),
            trip(4, listOf(4, 6), duration = 31, distance = 31.0),
            trip(3, listOf(9, 0), duration = 34, distance = 7.0),
            trip(5, listOf(3), duration = 25, distance = 33.0),
            trip(1, listOf(0, 7, 2, 3), duration = 13, distance = 17.0))
    )
}
```

Comment: I don't quite see why you want to group by a *range*. Why not simply `trips.groupBy { it.duration / 10 }` ?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Did not mention it. The task requires the return value to be an IntRange, that's why. :)

Comment: Could you provide some more information about the task? The more we know about what you want to accomplish and why, the easier it is to give a better answer.

Comment: Sure, just added the class, the task description and 2 task examples :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `it.duration` is quite long, you could use the alternative expression:

```
(it.duration / 10 * 10) .. (it.duration / 10 * 10 + 9)
```

You still have common subexpressions, though. To avoid these, you can define a cluster:

```
fun cluster(x: Double, size: Double) = (x - x % size) .. (x - x % size + size - 1)
```

or, to avoid the common subexpression:

```
fun cluster(x: Double, size: Double) = (x - x % size).let { it .. (it + size - 1) }
```

(I wrote the above without a compiler, so it may or may not work, but you get the idea.)

Then, you can group the trips by their cluster:

```
trips.groupBy { cluster(it.duration, 10.0) }
```

By the way, the group "30-39" also contains 39.999, so you might get contacted by a nitpicker that your range should better be called "[30,40)". ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [`with`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html) to avoid repeating the calculation of the [`start`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/start.html) of your [`IntRange`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/index.html).
2. You can use [`toInt`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-double/to-int.html) and integer division and multiplication as a more direct approach to calculating the `start` of your `IntRange` (similiar to how [Roland Illig](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/6499/roland-illig) [suggests](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/231368/91387)).
3. You can use [`until`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html) to clarify that your `IntRange`s are "[0,10)", "[10,20)", etc. which I think may be a bit clearer than "[0,9]", "[10,19]", etc. as the later will make readers think twice about if these ranges form a contiguous range or not whereas using closed-open ranges makes it, in my opinion, more clear.

Example:

```
val mappedTrips = trips.groupBy {
    with(it.duration.toInt() / 10 * 10) { this until this + 10 }
}
```